# Extjs, tab bar in items array, how to set simple mode not working

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.2

So I have the code below, and it works except the 'plain : true', which is suppose to remove the background color of the tabs. Is it because I'm not creating the object using something like this?

```
Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
    width: 300,
    height: 200,
    activeTab: 0,
    plain: true,
```

If I need to do it that way how do I do the Create command from within an items list?

```
Ext.define('My.view.TabContainer', {
    extend   : 'Ext.Container',
    xtype    : 'tabcontainer',
    layout : 'border',

    items : [

        {
            itemId   : 'theRealTabContainer',
            xtype    : 'tabpanel',
            plain    : true,
            region   : 'center',
            items    : [ 
                {  
                    xtype : 'company'
                }
                ,
                {
                   xtype : 'test'
               }
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No, what you're doing looks fine.  This looks like a bug after testing it out, but it only happens with a border layout as it's adding 'x-border-layout-ct' that is setting the background-color.  The tab panel is actually doing the right thing still.  You can do 2 things:

1. Add a class to the container (possibly an existing plain class from extjs or your own)
2. Set a style on the container

   ```
   Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
       layout: 'border',
       style: 'background-color: transparent !important',
   ```